# How to receive and parse json data fetched from one jsp page to another jsp page inside an ajax call?

Tags: json, ajax, jsp

I have a simple jsp page, which should show some english questions and their question ids fetched from a mysql database, but without reloading the page. For this purpose, I have used ajax in my jsp page demo.jsp, which will fetch data from another jsp page fetch.jsp. 
My problem is that I am not receiving any data in demo.jsp. What should I do?

demo.jsp

```
       <button onclick="fetch();">Fetch content</button>
       <br/>

       <table border="1px" width="500px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Qid</th>
                    <th>Question</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="content"></tbody>
        </table>
    <script>
            function fetch() {
                console.log("test 1");
                $.ajax({

                       url:"fetch.jsp",
                       dataType:"json",
                       success:function(res){
                           console.log("test 2");
                          var data="";
                          for(i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                              var p=$.JSONparse(res[i]);
                              data+="<tr><td>"+p.qid+"</td><td>"+p.question+"</td></tr>";
                          }
                          $('#status').html("Status : Content fetched");
                          $('#content').html(data);
                       },
                       error:function() {
                           alert("error occured");
                       }
                   });
           }
        </script>
```

fetch.jsp

```
<% 
String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jigyasa";
String user="root";
String pass="";

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

    try{
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    }catch(SQLException e){}

    try{

        String query;

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        query = "SELECT * FROM englishq";
        result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if(!result.next()){
            out.print("0");
        }else{
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
            do{
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("qid",result.getString("qid"));
                obj.put("question",result.getString("question"));
                System.out.println(result.getString("qid"));  
                System.out.println(result.getString("question")); 
                array.put(obj);

            }while(result.next());
             out.print(array.toString());

            out.flush();
         }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        out.print("Exception: "+e);
    } 

%>
```

Comment: check your console for error